# Get mouse click position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [this color wheel](https://github.com/bgrins/colorwheel-1k), and I want to add a black cover overlay to the color wheel, this way when the hsv's value changes (the v) using the slider under the color wheel, the color wheel will become darker.

I added a wrapper `div` to the `canvas`, and added another div (`overlay`) in the `wrapper`, and make the background color to black. I then set the position of the `wrapper` to `relative`, and for the `overlay`, I set the position to `absolute`.

(I set `wrapper` to `relative` so that `overlay` (with is `absolute`) will be contained in the `wrapper`.)

Because `wrapper` is set to `relative`, the color wheels selection isn't accurate. The picker doesn't follow the mouse exactly.

I think the problem can be solved with editing the following code: (In the `redraw()` function, on line 69.)

```
currentX = e.pageX - c.offsetLeft - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
currentY = e.pageY - c.offsetTop - radiusPlusOffset  || currentY;
```

But I don't know exactly what to change. How can I get the pickers pointer to follow the mouse even when `wrapper` is set to `relative`?

#### JSFiddle

```js
(function() {

  // Declare constants and variables to help with minification
  // Some of these are inlined (with comments to the side with the actual equation)
  var doc = document;
  doc.c = doc.createElement;
  b.a = b.appendChild;

  var width = c.width = c.height = 400,
    label = b.a(doc.c("p")),
    input = b.a(doc.c("input")),
    imageData = a.createImageData(width, width),
    pixels = imageData.data,
    oneHundred = input.value = input.max = 100,
    circleOffset = 10,
    diameter = 380, //width-circleOffset*2,
    radius = 190, //diameter / 2,
    radiusPlusOffset = 200, //radius + circleOffset
    radiusSquared = radius * radius,
    two55 = 255,
    currentY = oneHundred,
    currentX = -currentY,
    wheelPixel = 16040; // circleOffset*4*width+circleOffset*4;

  // Math helpers
  var math = Math,
    PI = math.PI,
    PI2 = PI * 2,
    sqrt = math.sqrt,
    atan2 = math.atan2;

  // Setup DOM properties
  b.style.textAlign = "center";
  label.style.font = "2em courier";
  input.type = "range";

  // Load color wheel data into memory.
  for (y = input.min = 0; y < width; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      var rx = x - radius,
        ry = y - radius,
        d = rx * rx + ry * ry,
        rgb = hsvToRgb(
          (atan2(ry, rx) + PI) / PI2, // Hue
          sqrt(d) / radius, // Saturation
          1 // Value
        );

      // Print current color, but hide if outside the area of the circle
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[0];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[1];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = rgb[2];
      pixels[wheelPixel++] = d > radiusSquared ? 0 : two55;
    }
  }

  // Bind Event Handlers
  input.onchange = redraw;
  c.onmousedown = doc.onmouseup = function(e) {
    // Unbind mousemove if this is a mouseup event, or bind mousemove if this a mousedown event
    doc.onmousemove = /p/.test(e.type) ? 0 : (redraw(e), redraw);
  }

  // Handle manual calls + mousemove event handler + input change event handler all in one place.
  function redraw(e) {

    // Only process an actual change if it is triggered by the mousemove or mousedown event.
    // Otherwise e.pageX will be undefined, which will cause the result to be NaN, so it will fallback to the current value
    currentX = e.pageX - c.offsetLeft - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
    currentY = e.pageY - c.offsetTop - radiusPlusOffset || currentY;

    // Scope these locally so the compiler will minify the names.  Will manually remove the 'var' keyword in the minified version.
    var theta = atan2(currentY, currentX),
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;

    // If the x/y is not in the circle, find angle between center and mouse point:
    //   Draw a line at that angle from center with the distance of radius
    //   Use that point on the circumference as the draggable location
    if (d > radiusSquared) {
      currentX = radius * math.cos(theta);
      currentY = radius * math.sin(theta);
      theta = atan2(currentY, currentX);
      d = currentX * currentX + currentY * currentY;
    }

    label.textContent = b.style.background = hsvToRgb(
      (theta + PI) / PI2, // Current hue (how many degrees along the circle)
      sqrt(d) / radius, // Current saturation (how close to the middle)
      input.value / oneHundred // Current value (input type="range" slider value)
    )[3];

    // Reset to color wheel and draw a spot on the current location. 
    a.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // Heart:
    a.font = "1em arial";
    a.fillText("♥", currentX + radiusPlusOffset - 4, currentY + radiusPlusOffset + 4);

  }

  // Created a shorter version of the HSV to RGB conversion function in TinyColor
  // https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor/blob/master/tinycolor.js
  function hsvToRgb(h, s, v) {
    h *= 6;
    var i = ~~h,
      f = h - i,
      p = v * (1 - s),
      q = v * (1 - f * s),
      t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s),
      mod = i % 6,
      r = [v, q, p, p, t, v][mod] * two55,
      g = [t, v, v, q, p, p][mod] * two55,
      b = [p, p, t, v, v, q][mod] * two55;

    return [r, g, b, "rgb(" + ~~r + "," + ~~g + "," + ~~b + ")"];
  }

  // Kick everything off
  redraw(0);

  /*
  // Just an idea I had to kick everything off with some changing colors…
  // Probably no way to squeeze this into 1k, but it could probably be a lot smaller than this:
  currentX = currentY = 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      currentX--;
      currentY*=1.05;
      redraw(0)
  }, 7);
    
  setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(interval)
  }, 700)
  */

})();
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#blackBackground {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
  sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
  elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
  Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit
  vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh.
  Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="blackBackground"></div>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
  var b = document.body;
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var a = c.getContext('2d');
  document.body.clientWidth; // fix bug in webkit: http://qfox.nl/weblog/218
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the last script tag (just after `var c = ...`):

```
var w = document.getElementById('wrapper');
```

then You can get and substract the wrapper offset properties:

```
currentX = e.pageX - w.offsetLeft - c.offsetLeft - radiusPlusOffset || currentX;
currentY = e.pageY - w.offsetTop - c.offsetTop - radiusPlusOffset || currentY;
```